# How do I open a new storyboard from custom controller class in Xamarin.ios native app?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

We are using custom controller class to bind UITableView in xamarin.ios, so we need to open a new storyboard on a image tap gesture event. How to open new storyboard/controller?
When we write a code in tap gesture event its showing compile Time error, please see code below,

UIStoryboard st = this.Storyboard; 
 clsNewStoryboard CRVC = clsNewStoryboard)st.InstantiateViewController(“NewStoryboard”);                      this.PresentViewController(CRVC, true, null);

So we have create a method in our main viewController class and write same code I.e mention above,
Now its throw runtime error “Object reference not set to an instance to object”.

How to solve this issue.. please guide/help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way is you can create StoryBoard reference from present storyboard to new StoryBoard and call PerformSegue on tap gesture event.

```
                OR
```

Programatically you can do it by using the code below

```
UIStoryboard newStoryBoard = UIStoryboard.FromName("NewStoryBoardName", null);
UIViewController viewControllerYouWantToLoad = (ViewControllerYouWantToLoad)newStoryBoard.InstantiateViewController(ViewControllerYouWantToLoadIdentifier);
PresentViewController(viewControllerYouWantToLoad, true, null);
```

Comment: Hi Its not working because we are using custom cell class to bind our controls. Custom cell class does't have any PerformSegue. While we are using code that you suggested, we put the storyboard Id as  name parameter, but its throw exception "Could not find a storyboard named".

Comment: Don't give the storyboard ID, Instead give StoryBoard name itself. If you want to do PerformSegue from custom cell, Create Segue from parent viewcontroller and Use Delegates or Blocks to give a callback from your custom cell to parent viewcontroller and call PerformSegue in the callback.